How can a man and woman get married if they are stranded on an island?
If a man and a woman, complete strangers (both Muslims) who are not married and are non mahram to each other, are stranded on an island, where no other human is present. How can they get married?

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. Please note we are not a fatwa site and as you may know nikah requires at least 2 witnesses and  the consent of the wali of a woman.

The view of the majority of the jurists is that marriage requires the presence of the guardian of the bride and two witnesses. This is based on the hadith:

لا نكاح إلا بولي وشاهدي عدل، وما كان من نكاح على غير ذلك، فهو باطل
There is no marriage except with a guardian and two witnesses of good character. And the Nikah which is without them is invalid.
— Saheeh Ibn Hibban  , Sunan al-Kubra Bayhaqi, Saheeh al-Jaami‘

So in your case those two should refrain from marriage until they are rescued or manage to build a boat and travel to a place where the prerequisites of marriage can be fulfilled. This is also what they would have to anyways if they had been stranded alone, or with someone whom they could not marry.
IslamQA has a related fatwa on marriage in a place where there are no other Muslims to act as witnesses, see https://islamqa.info/ar/answers/154356
